# How to assign returned function value to a const global variable

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to compile a lib with a global (I need it), but i need to initialize this constant global with the returned pointer of a function.
But GCC don't want to assign a variable value to my global, if someone could have a solution.

```
error: initializer element is not constant
t_page_meta_data *const begin_meta_data = (t_page_meta_data *const)alloc_page(1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to assign a variable value to a 'constant global variable ' ?

Comment: Yes i want to initialize the global with the value returned by my function.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this in C, but you can in C++.

Comment: Assuming the function contains some sort of static calculation that can be carried out at compile-time, the normal procedure in C is to use a macro.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do this in C with a `const` global variable. However if you still want to expose some read-only global you could do something like this:

```
static t_page_meta_data *real_begin_meta_data;
t_page_meta_data *const *const begin_meta_data = &real_begin_meta_data;

int main()
{
    real_begin_meta_data = (t_page_meta_data*)alloc_page(1);
    // begin_meta_data = NULL  <= error
    // *begin_meta_data = NULL <= error
}
```

`begin_meta_data` would be exposed as a global variable pointing to the `static` variable `real_begin_meta_data`. It's an extra level of indirection for users of the global but it works. Note that `**begin_meta_data` is non-const - this is equivalent to `*begin_meta_data` being non-const in the code in your question.

Another way to do this is to just use a function instead of a global variable:

```
static t_page_meta_data *real_begin_meta_data;
t_page_meta_data *begin_meta_data()
{
    return real_begin_meta_data;
}

int main()
{
    real_begin_meta_data = (t_page_meta_data*)alloc_page(1);
}
```

Now users just use `begin_meta_data()` to get the pointer. Obviously they can't change what it points to since they can't see `real_begin_meta_data`. But they can still modify `*begin_meta_data()` like in your code.

Comment: This only makes the pointer const though. The pointed-at data can still be accessed, making this as bad as having `real_value` as a global variable. I assume you meant to use `const int* const`.

Comment: I did at first but then I saw that OP has a const pointer to non-const. So I think this fits OP's needs more. I'll edit to have `real_value` be a pointer itself to match OP better.

Comment: That probably means that the OP:s code doesn't make any sense, more than anything else.

Comment: Or that OP wants `begin_meta_data` to always point to the same thing but have the data it points to be modifiable.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i will work on it.